# Convert FoxPro function to php

Tags: php, foxpro

I have been asked/told to convert a foxpro function to PHP, however I know nothing about foxpro.

```
PARAMETERS cCkey
LOCAL cKey
cKey = SUBSTR(SYS(2015),2)+PADL(LTRIM(STR(INT(IIF(INT(RAND()*1000000000) =   851390329,RAND(-1),RAND())*1000000),6)),6,"0")

RETURN cKey
```

Above is the function they are wanting to use in a system that is being built in php to integrate with the foxpro databases.

Some of the functions are familiar from PHP, but others like the "SYS", and "IIF" are not, and being that I know someone on here will be able to take one look at it, and know exactly what it is doing.

Mind helping me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for the information on the functions. Any ideas how to write the function in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sys(2015)** is a handy VFP function which returns a value unique to that session of VFP. You can read it [here](http://fox.wikis.com/wc.dll?Wiki~FunctionSys2015)

**Iif** is inline if-else-endif statement .. like Excel does

Updated

SYS(2015) in PHP ? I don't know .. but if we  talking about random string in PHP, you can use this

```
function rand_string( $length ) {
    $chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";  

    $size = strlen( $chars );
    for( $i = 0; $i < $length; $i++ ) {
        $str .= $chars[ rand( 0, $size - 1 ) ];
    }

    return $str;
}
```

I got that from [this link](http://www.lateralcode.com/creating-a-random-string-with-php/) and got the basic idea from [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/192353)

About the other part MAYBE like this :

```
$randomresult = 0
$srandom = ""

If (INT(RAND()*1000000000) =   851390329)
{
    $randomresult = int(rand(-1)) * 1000000
}
else
{
    $randomresult = int(rand()) * 1000000
}

$srandom=str_pad(ltrim(strval($randomresult),"0")),6,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

So, MAYBE we can make the foxpro code like this in PHP :

```
$cKey = rand_string(10) . str_pad(ltrim(strval($randomresult),"0")),6,"0",STR_PAD_LEFT)
```

At least you can the idea .....

Comment: Any suggestions how to write that function in PHP?

Comment: Thanks, that should get them started, from there they can do what they need with it.

Answer (score 0):

`SYS(2015)` Returns a unique 10-character procedure name that begins with an underscore followed by a combination of letters and numbers.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/684by7c1(v=vs.80).aspx

`IIF` Returns one of two values depending on the value of a logical expression.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ttt15k6(v=vs.80).aspx

With this information I think you can at least take a stab at creating a PHP function and then showing some PHP and asking for help if needed.